# Дан отсортированный массив, число X, нужно найти два элемента сумма равна X, иначе вывести 0. O(nlogn)) (бинарный поиск)

Tags: php, алгоритм

```
$i = 0;
$j = count($array) - 1;

while ($i < $j) {
    $sum = (int) $array[$i] + (int) $array[$j];
    if ($sum == $k) {
        echo "ok";
        break;
    }

    if ($sum > $k) {
        $j--;
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}

if ($i == $j) {
    echo "no";
}
```

Это оказывается O(n)

Comment: Вопрос то в чем?

Comment: Если вы ищете решение за *NlogN*, то это странно. У вас уже есть решение быстрее. Если вы ищете решение за *logN*, то это невозможно. Можно показать что любой правильный алгоритм работает за *N* или  медленнее.

Comment: `O(N)` явно быстрее, чем `O(N log N)`.  Предложенный алгоритм можно как-то оптимизировать для граничных случаев, например, если `X < arr[0]` или `X > 2 * arr[N - 1]`, то решения не будет, но в общем случае сложность всё равно будет `O(N)`

Comment: Если у вас стоит задача искать именно за O(nlogn), несмотря на то, что есть лучшее решение, то двигайте левый индекс в цикле, и ищите правый элемент бинарным поиском в оставшейся части массива.